# Trouble with Makefile compiling objects and moving them

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

This is my Makefile:

```
.PHONY : clean fclean re $(LIB_PATH) 

NAME = fillit

FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

LIB_NAME = libft.a

LIB_DIR = ../libft/

LIB_PATH = $(LIB_DIR)$(LIB_NAME)

OBJ_DIR_NAME = objects

OBJ_DIR = $(OBJ_DIR_NAME)/

HEADER_DIR = ../libft/

SRC = main.c func1.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

all :
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR_NAME)
    $(MAKE) $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ) $(LIB_PATH)
    gcc -o $(NAME) $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(OBJ)) -L$(LIB_DIR) -lft -I$(HEADER_DIR)

$(LIB_PATH):
    $(MAKE) -C $(LIB_DIR) --no-print-directory

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : %.c
    gcc $(FLAGS) -I $(HEADER_DIR) -c $<
    -mv $(@F) $(OBJ_DIR)

clean : 
    -rm $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(OBJ))
    -rm -rv $(OBJ_DIR_NAME)

fclean : clean
    -rm $(NAME)
    $(MAKE) -C $(LIB_DIR) fclean --no-print-directory

re: fclean
    make
```

When i do make, i expect that the rule `$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : %.c` compiles the two objects (func1.c main.c) and move them to objects directory. But the rule only happens with the first source file written in `SRC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> compiles the two objects (reader.c main.c)

Did you mean `func1.c` instead of `reader.c`?

If that is the case, please check if the `func1.c` file is in the same directory as `main.c`. If it isn't in the same directory, you'll have to write another pattern rule. Something like this:

```
FUNC1_DIR = # The directory where your func1.c is located, maybe src/ or something alike

$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : $(FUNC1_DIR)%.c
    gcc $(FLAGS) -I $(HEADER_DIR) -c $<
    -mv $(@F) $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Comment: Yes was func1.c i have edited it already sorry.

They are at the same directory and what's more if i write `$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)main.o $(OBJ_DIR)func1.o $(LIB_PATH)` instead of `$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ) $(LIB_PATH)` works perfectly.

Comment: Well, it seems that in `$(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ)` the `$(OBJ_DIR)` only works for the first file in `$(OBJ)`, this means the `main.o` will build perfectly because its path is correct, but `func1.o` will not build because the path was not added and so the complier thinks the file is in the same directory as the Makefile.   Try this: `OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_DIR)%.o,$(SRC)` instead of `OBJ = main.o func1.o`. And then also remove the `$(OBJ_DIR)` from the line `$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ) $(LIB_PATH)`.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to add a path to the src-files in `$(patsubst )`, something like this: `OBJ = $(patsubst  $(SRC_DIR)%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)%.o,$(SRC))`, it depends where your src files are. And you can find some more information about patsubst in the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions). I hope this helps :)

Comment: Now works, thank you but apparently its the same that i wrote why before didnt take the two objects?

Comment: If you write `$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ) $(LIB_PATH)` it is the same as `fillit: objects/main.o func1.o $(LIB_PATH)`. If you generate `OBJ` with patsubst, it will be: `OBJ = objects/main.o objects/func1.o`. So every .o file has the correct path. And that means `$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(LIB_PATH)` will now be `fillit: objects/main.o objects/func1.o $(LIB_PATH)`

Answer (score 0):

`$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ)` doesn't apply $(OBJDIR) to each item $(OBJ).
It literally just concatenates $(OBJDIR) onto the list.  This is why only one instance of your pattern rule fires (only one .o has the path prefix that the pattern is trying to match).

Instead, use:

```
OBJ_WITH_PATH := $(foreach obj,$(OBJ),$(OBJ_DIR)$(obj))
```

Then update the dependency on your NAME rule to

```
$(NAME): $(OBJ_WITH_PATH) $(LIB_PATH)
```

As an aside, I find it is sometimes helpful to add rules like

```
.PHONY: DEBUG
DEBUG:
    @echo MAKING SURE THIS WORKS: $(OBJ_DIR)$(OBJ)
    @echo ALTERNATE: $(OBJ_WITH_PATH)
```

then you can run your DEBUG target:

```
$ make DEBUG
MAKING SURE THIS WORKS temp/a.o b.o
ALT temp/a.o temp/b.o
```